# Do Matrices have to be square when using LU Factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Just curious. Learning LU Factorization and came across a comment on an assignment where it said LU factorization uses square matrices. Is this true?

My problem is $\begin {bmatrix} 2&-6&6\\ -4&5&-7\\ 3&5&-1\\ -6&4&-8\\ 8&-3&9\\ \end {bmatrix}$

Just to explain LU Factorization (as I understand it) I know I need to use row factorization to get the upper half of the matrix (the $U$ part) and then I use that to get the lower (L part). I'm using a different method in order to get the lower half of the factorization (it's hard for me to describe without an example) but is it also possible to get the lower half through row operations.

Comment: They don't have to be, I highly recommend you to have a look at the book http://saba.kntu.ac.ir/eecd/sedghizadeh/Ebooks/Matrix_Analysis.pdf, there you can find how to do it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LU decomposition on 5 by 3 matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513252/lu-decomposition-on-5-by-3-matrix)